# Is there a way to make tab content appear without sliding in?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

With `md-tabs`, is there a way to make content appear without sliding in when selecting a tab with [Tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)?

None of the [options](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs) seem to indicate a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the content to just show up without the sliding you can set the css to stop the transition effect like this:

```
md-tab-content{
   transition: none;
}
```